# How do I get past error #1064 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I keep getting the same error when I try to  use stored procedures.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mmStudents
AS 
SELECT * FROM student where course 'mm'
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS SELECT * FROM student where course 'mm'' at line 2

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That looks more like you are trying to create a view. Please refer to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) on the correct syntax for stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL Store Procedure doesn't have `AS` keyword. It should be

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mmStudents()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM student where course = 'mm';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Does the syntax differ on different servers?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN SELECT * FROM student where course = 'mm'; END' at line 2

Comment: did you add `()` at the end of procedure name?

Comment: You hero, that worked. Do I have to use that delimiter with every procedure now?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an operator for your where clause

```
SELECT * FROM student where course = 'mm'
```

for example.

From [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html)

> The parameter list enclosed within parentheses must always be present. If there are no parameters, an empty parameter list of () should be used.

So your complete statement should be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mmStudents()
SELECT * FROM student where course = 'mm'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should take a look on MySQL [documentation to Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

There is a good example there on how to create stored procedures.

Hope it helps!